# Windows 10 doesn't shut down properly

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have visited tons of websites and watched dozens of Youtube videos, yet I can't find a solution to my problem.

I recently upgraded my laptop to Windows 10, and now it won't shutdown properly.

I **have turned off fast startup and sleep mode** from power options.

Here is what happens:

1. Start menu > Power > Shut down
2. It exits windows and apparently turns off (black screen)
3. The power lights are still on and my computer apparently doesn't shutdown.

Comment: I also had this problem sometimes with my Windows 10 TP. Even worse, seems like the CPU gets stuck in an infinite loop, the system generates a lot of heat and fans spin to their maximum :o. I'm going to reinstall the OS anyway, i'll see if this happen again.

Comment: I had a similar problem when i was restarting my Windows 10 PC. The HDD was not doing anything, yet my PC was still on. For me, a Windows Update service glitch was the problem.To solve the problem, type in cmd with admin rights the following: *net stop wuauserv* [then] *cd %systemroot%* [then] *ren SoftwareDistribution SD.old* [then] *net start wuauserv*

Comment: I found this happens if the partition containing either \Windows or \Boot is not marked Active/Bootable (unsure which is important, most likely \Boot, and they are often colocated).

Comment: I had the same problem on my lenovo thinkpad yoga 14. I held the power button in for a few seconds and the power light went off.

Comment: @snaks20 did the problem then come back for you? (currently suffering the same problem started about 2 weeks after getting win10 will check your idea there in the evening)

Comment: @Thomas To be honest, sometimes it hangs up while starting an application(.exe file), but it hasn't happened again during a restart or shutdown.I haven't used my method since a long time ago.

Comment: @snaks20 tnx will try that there.

Comment: @snaks20 tnx your method worked very well and corrected my problem

Comment: I have fixed this problem by installing the Intel Device Manager V9

http://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/inbsd1/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=KV645&fileId=3362328587&osCode=WB64A&productCode=inspiron-15-3537&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS

Comment: @afonso-matos, did you solve the issue? I have the same problem. Tried the same you did and did not solve. I do NOT have intel processor, so the issue is not the bug  with the intel MAnagement Engine driver (https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/382344/how-to-solve-windows-10-shutdown-issues-power-keyboard-lights-are-still-on). I have Windows 10 on a Lenovo Z50 with an AMD FX-7500 Radeon R7. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 21):

This worked for me:

Device Manager/ System Devices/ Intel(R) Management Engine Interface

Then: right click properties and select driver (currently version 11.xxx), uninstall and OK.

Next reboot, check driver - should have rolled back to an earlier version, mine is 9.5

Comment: do we check the "Delete the driver software for this device" checkbox when we uninstall? Thanks

Comment: This worked for me for an issue with a Lenovo M81, it rolled back to version ~7 - note that you _**must** disable fast startup_ in the power options.

Comment: @user22105 - Don't select check box "Delete the driver....", other wise you need to manually download the version and install it. batter to try roll-back option before uninstall it.

Comment: @U2Answer Too late, didn't check the comments before doing the thing. How do I manually install it now? ty

Comment: @GuiImamura - I have put that comment for others newcomer, they might get answer while referring this thread.

Manual Installation mean you need to download appropriate driver version from web and install it.

Comment: I have the same problem with my HP Pavilion 15 and this solution didn't work for me!

Comment: My driver version didn't change but this fixed my issue with an Acer Aspire "V" laptop.

Comment: You can also disable the device and re-enable it later if it doesn't fix the issue. For me, simply disabling it solved everything.

Comment: It is almost the solution for my ThinkPad lenovo E530c with installing IME 9.5 driver . http://support.lenovo.com/de/en/downloads/DS038194. and rollback and enable and disable this driver finally all my standby,restart shutdown problems solved. but my current IME interface driver is 11.0.0.1181. I think resetting some setting during this process solved the problem

Comment: I've uninstalled and it reinstalled automatically on the same version but... now it works.

Comment: I have an intel i5 M520, but there's no `Intel(R) Management Engine Interface` entry in the device manager and my laptop vendor does not provide a ME driver, so no fix for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try these tests:

Hold down the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and tap <kbd>R</kbd> and type `shutdown /s /t 5` in the Run field. Then tap the Enter key.

or

Run CMD window as admin (black menu with white text)

`shutdown /s /t 5`

These commands tell the machine to shutdown completely (bypassing hybrid shutdown)  after a 5 second delay.

Does it work? Then use either of those to shutdown the computer.

You can also run `shutdown /r /t 5` to restart the computer.

If you still cannot shut down, try to look for system errors using CMD as admin `sfc /scannow`

Or, try `chkdsk c: /f` out of CMD window as admin to possibly fix drive errors.

Comment: The commands didn't work and no drive errors show up. Problem remains.

Comment: Not to sound like a smarty, but did you use a space between the command characters?   shutdown (space) /r (space) /t (space) 5

Comment: I know how to use the command line mike.

Comment: @mikewestern I have the same problem as catgocat. I had it previously in Windows 8.1, where I solved it by disabling hybrid shutdown in power plan options. I upgraded to Win 10 a couple days ago and despite that option still being disabled my PC stopped shutting down properly. But I just tried your command line solution and for me it works. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the exact same problem. I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3542.  Follow the steps given below.

1. open device manager.
2. expand network adapters.
3. update drivers for "Dell Wireless 1705 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHZ)" and    "Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller Properties".
4. then open properties for "Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller Properties".
5. open "power management" and check first two boxes.
6. click OK.  close device manager.
7. restart your laptop.
8. now shut down to check if your problem solved.

Mine was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar shutdown problem when I upgraded my Dell Studio from Win7 to Win10 3 days back.
Fortunately I have dual OS, Win10 and OpenSUSE 12.1 linux.
I restart the machine in OpenSUSE and do shutdown from Linux, thus avoiding the over heating and blowing off  of the m/c.

This is a way out, till appropriate Drivers for Win10 are found for the given h/w and permanent solution to the problem.

MP

Comment: do you have any reference about your statements?

Comment: What reference do you need?

Comment: you are suggesting the drivers are the couse of the problem, how do you determinate that?

Comment: There were no issues with Win7 earlier and there are no issues with Linux now, so obviously its not the problem of H/w. It has to be the issue with communication between H/w and a particular O/s. Hence, driver issues..

Comment: Drivers for Win 10

Comment: there could be many couses, malware,viruses,process..also drivers, the most commonly step to folow is go to see what event viewer shows, the question is very vague because the op do not provide even the hardware details.

Comment: You're right. It's the Intel Management Engine Interface drivers that are causing the issue. Rolling back to a pre-10 version solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is due to the new Windows 10 shutdown process. Here is the solution:

Do not close your laptop's lid immediately after the screen goes blank; leave it for a minutes and then close the lid. If you close it suddenly after the screen goes blank, the computer will go into sleep mode because the shutdown process has not completed yet.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question. The question says "I have turned off fast startup and sleep mode from power options." so sleep mode is disabled.