# Shutdown button (Start Menu & Login Screen) logs out but doesn't shut down in Windows 10 Desktop PC

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I have googled this issue and found a lot of problems like this for laptops but none for desktops.

My Windows 10 machine appears to being shutting down but then it does not. I use the start menu and then click power -> shutdown. I also use the shutdown button from the log in screen and it does the same thing. Just appears to be shutting down but never does. It does log me out though.

Command line shuts my PC down fine with "shutdown /s". This is not a solution. I want my power off(shutdown) buttons to SHUTDOWN my PC instead of logging me out.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

The proposed duplicate question deals with Win 10 shutdown problems, but different issues and the solutions do not apply.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 10 doesn't shut down properly](http://superuser.com/questions/957433/windows-10-doesnt-shut-down-properly)

Comment: Not a duplicate, read the question Charlie

Comment: No offense to you, so don't take this personal. There has to be 5 votes to close a question. If no one agrees with me, this will stay open. I voted as duplicate because they both have to do with Windows 10 not shutting down properly, regardless of what the platform. Neither question definitively isolate the architecture as being the cause. If you have proof it is specific to your computer being a desktop, then edit your question to include those details.

Comment: @CharlieRB The title says it's for a desktop. My first sentence says it's for a desktop. The question you linked to talks about a laptop. The answers for the laptop talk about the sleep and hybernate and closing of the lid being issues. pretty clear mate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make the shutdown buttons shutdown the PC you have to change some settings in the power options.

1. Navigate to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\System Settings
2. Click on the text which says "Change Settings that are currently unavailable"
3. Uncheck "Turn on fast startup (recommended)"
4. click "Save changes" at the bottom of the screen

Comment: To be clear, Click on "Choose what the power buttons do" in Power Options.

Comment: This is rare, I migrated the OS from a HDD to a SSD, and this problem appears with the SSD, not with the HDD. Hopefully, your solution fixes it (as expense of some slowness at shutdown)

Comment: why do I have to uncheck fast startup? It's not a solution, it's disabling a feature! It worked with previous Windows installation until I reinstalled it

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the Power options; also try shutting down using the [shutdown command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx) in the Run dialog <kbd>Win-R</kbd>:

```
shutdown -s -t 00
```

or, to force shutdown,

```
shutdown -f -s -t 00
```

If that works, copy it to a batch (text) file named *myshutdown.bat* (or any filename with .bat extension); create a shortcut in the start menu for convenience and to make a keyboard shortcut.

You can *try* the *-h* (hibernate) option, but it is deprecated, as MS seems to have found it unreliable since Windows 8.

Comment: DrMoishe, you are almost there. The answer is in Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Power Options\System Settings. You have to click a button called "Change Settings that are currently unavailable" and then you uncheck "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" and click "Save changes" at the bottom of the screen. Then my desktop shuts down properly. If you alter your answer to highlight(put it at the top of the answer) what fixed my problem then I'll mark your answer as correct. It was the one which led me to the real solution at the end.

Answer (score 1):

[Starting with Windows 8, Microsoft changed the way how Windows boots](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/09/08/delivering-fast-boot-times-in-windows-8.aspx) to make it faster. This is called HybridBoot and is a logoff + hibernation. Next time Windows starts it resumes the kernel from hibernation and after login it starts your startup tools as in all older versions. To do a full shutdown you have to press the SHIFT key and press the Shutdown button.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i am wrong as i haven't go through this situation.

If you are using Internet on your PC, then it might happen that OS get update as windows 10 is having alot of issues with Update, so shutdown take some time sometimes it happen that pc don't shutdown and after 2-3 minutes it automatically update your system. Might be that is the reason.

Comment: Nah, it was on for 5 days straight. No updates being applied or restarts. Just takes me to the log out screen. Power supply still running, fans still running, USB devices still running, Windows still running. All for days with multiple presses of the "shutdown" buttons. All sorted now as per my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

To make the shutdown button actually shutdown the PC, I had to change some settings in the power options.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to Control Panel → All Control Panel Items → Power Options → System Settings.
2. Click on the text which says "Change Settings that are currently unavailable".
3. Uncheck "Sleep". (This removes Sleep as an option in the Start Menu power options, but it solved the problem with shutting down, and I could still 'hibernate' if I wanted to)
4. Click "Save changes" at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: how the sleep option is related to the shutdown option behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make a reply here as I've been struggling with this issue for the past 6 hours since a power cut screwed up my PC. I had the exact issues described here and in various other threads I found on Google i.e. hibernate sends to lock screen and shut down only works if fast boot is disabled. I have now fixed the issue and wanted to share my solution:

Intuition may tell you that an issue like this is not related to the BIOS, and you'd be wrong. I spent hours messing with everything in Windows, messing with commands and toggling settings, creating a USB bootable Ubuntu drive to manually delete the hibernation file in case it was corrupted, all to no avail.

First of all I'd recommend going into your BIOS and noting down your current settings so they can be put back later. Now then...

The answer was to open my PC, re-seat all my RAM sticks and re-seat my GPU. Then, remove the CMOS battery, switch all power to the PC off (e.g. with the power switch by the AC plug port) and hold the power on button for a few seconds to ensure there is no power left in the system. Now power on the PC WITH THE BATTERY REMOVED. If / when you get a prompt telling you to setup the BIOS, only do REQUIRED settings i.e. for most people no changes at all, then save and reset to boot to Windows. Now test the hibernate / shutdown functions. Hopefully they'll work. If not, still don't rule out resetting the BIOS / CMOS battery. It was on the second attempt 4 hours after my initial attempt with this that I did it correctly and got results. Once it's acting normally again, shut it down and reinsert the battery. Boot again to ensure it works properly. If so, you can restart and go re-configure your BIOS to how you like it. Now my PC is running perfect, whereas before I thought some key files had to have been corrupted or something when the power cut!

Note: I want to emphasise that by removing the battery and power you want your BIOS settings to reset to factory settings. If you attempt this and notice your settings are still there, it hasn't worked properly. If you had a BIOS password set and it's still asking you for one, it hasn't worked properly. In fact, I think a good way to test whether it worked is to first set a password and ensure it's gone after you've done the process.

Best of luck!

Comment: well it's just random things to reset bios, also why did  you need to re-seat RAM and GPU?