# Windows 10 doesn't shut off properly (power light remains on) after long period of use

Tags: windows, power-management

I've recently upgraded to Windows 10, but I'm encountering an issue with the shut down of the computer everyday. If I stay on Windows 10 for a long period of time (~2 hours or longer) say doing office work or browsing the web etc etc, I would have trouble shutting down the machine completely. The screen would go black, but the power light would stay on. I would have to press the power button for roughly 10 seconds to do a hard shut off. However, if I turn on the computer and turn it off within 10 minutes or so, the computer would shut down completely without problem.

I've researched on the issue, and *turned off the fast startup*. I also followed the solutions from this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/957433/windows-10-doesnt-shut-down-properly) on Superuser addressing a similar or almost the same problem, but none of the solution has worked in my case. Is there anything else I can do to resolve the issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good solution that seems to have worked for many people:

1. Go to power options click
2. Click on `Choose what the power buttons do`
3. Under `Shutdown Settings`, uncheck `Turn on fast startup`
4. Click save

Note: If the `Turn on fast startup` area is grayed out, click on `Change settings that are currently unavailable` located at the top of the window.

This method seems to be hit or miss for some reason, so let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Dr. Zoo thank you for your input! I've already unchecked the "Turn on fast startup" checkbox prior to creating this thread. The solution did not work for me. I've also tried shutting down with the command "shutdown /s /t 5", as another thread on Superuser had suggested, but neither solution worked in my case :(

Comment: Ah dang. That solution is really spotty for some reason. Have you looked at event viewer to see if it comes up with any odd errors after trying to shut down?

Comment: I have indeed done that, but there are many errors, it's hard to tell which error was causing the issue... I try to check the time stamp on errors that were close to the shut down, I find errors like kernel errors, security SPP, DistributedCOM, Apps.

Comment: I do changes according to your suggestions but till fetching same issues.